# Build static gdb 11.2 with cross compiler

Tags: gdb, cross-compiling, arm64, gdbserver

Anyone success to build static gdb (not gdbserver) version 11.2 with cross compiler (arm64) ?
I'm not sure which flags (in CFLAGS and LDFLAGS) make gdb to build as static,
I tried to pass "-static" and more various flags,
Thanks,

Comment: "...gdb (not gdbserver) ... with cross compiler..." -- So you are trying to build (using a x86_64-hosted cross-compiler) a static-linked `gdb` executable intended to run on an arm64 target? Did I understand that correctly? Is your cross-compiler setup tested to be functioning as expected?

Comment: Yes, Of course,
Here (https://github.com/hugsy/gdb-static) you can see result of someone done build like this

Comment: "Yes of course" that is what you are trying to do, or "yes of course" you have tested your cross-compiler being able to create static binaries for your arm64 target? And what *exactly* have you tried (which commands), and what *exactly* is your problem (which error message)?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do static own build of static gdb will run on aarch64 architecture.
finally, I want to do static compilation of gdb debugger to run on linux aarch64 host
I did not get any error messages in compilation, 
actually, I success to compile dynamically without errors even though I pass flags like a "-static"

Comment: So you get a dynamically linked executable although you are specifying a static link? If yes, can you reproduce that problem with a "hello world" kind of source instead of `gdb`? Then your question would become much more simple: "How to cross-compile a statically linked executable"... (Trying to pinpoint the actual issue at hand, while at the same time making the question more generally useful / interesting.)

Comment: At first I want to thank to for your help,
I did compilation with relevant flags of "Hello World" program with success !
Unfortunately, with gdb it does not work, therefore I post this issue.